# DeprecattionWarning: 'node --debug' and 'node --debug-brk' are invalid. please use 'node --inspect or 'node --inspect-brk' insted

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

When I am running node.js app in visual studio I am getting this: `DeprecationWarning: 'node --debug' and 'node --debug-brk' are invalid.`

Please use 'node --inspect or 'node --inspect-brk' instead. in command promt.

Answer (score 0):

node --debug and node --debug-brk are all used to debug in node versions before 7.7.0

> The legacy debugger has been deprecated as of Node 7.7.0. Please use -->inspect and Inspector instead.

vscode uses a combination of "--inspect --debug-brk" to enter into debug mode across all node versions

[See the response from member of vscode team](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27731#issuecomment-305265014)